# Find uncommon data from two tables in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

i am using a category , product relation to find data. I am in situation like i have a category table and product table with categoryid and product type. No suppose i have a particular type and i want to find those category which a product of a specific type does not have.
 Table struture are like

```
Category Table
____________
|Id|Category|
| 1|    X   |
_____________

Product Table
____________________________
|ID | Product|Category| Type|
| 1 | Y      | 1      | 2   |
_____________________________
```

I can find it by using a sub query like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   category 
WHERE  id NOT IN(SELECT category 
                 FROM   product 
                 WHERE  type = 2);
```

**Is there a way to get it by another way**

I also use a JOIN like

```
SELECT * 
FROM   category AS c 
       JOIN products AS p 
         ON c.id <> p.category 
WHERE  p.type = 2
```

**Why does this not give the appropriate result.**

Comment: If you have `a JOIN b ON a.id <> b.id` what you are doing is `join each row from 'a' and join it to every row from 'b' where the id's are different`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and use `IS NULL` predicate:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   category AS c 
       LEFT JOIN products AS p 
              ON c.id = p.category 
                 AND p.type = 2 
WHERE  p.category IS NULL;
```

The unmatched rows from the second table will have null values in the `category` field, the `WHERE p.category IS NULL` will filter and give you them